# Form for taggable post model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working in a form for post than can have tags. The relationship is a classic `has_and_belongs_to_many` between `Post` and `Tag`.

Problem is I can't initialize a post with an array of tag ids, like this:

```ruby
Post.new(tags: [1, 2, 3, 4]) # won't wotk. ActiveRecord expects Tag instances
```

So my current form is like this:

```ruby
= form_for @post do |f|
    = f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'title...'
    = f.text_area :body
    = fields_for :'post[tags]' do |ft| # hacky. using @post.tags raised 'undefined `model name` for `@post.tags`'
      - Post.tags.each do |tag| # I defined Post::tags since I can't Acces Tag class here
          = ft.check_box tag.id
          = tag.name
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

This form forces me to hack a little in either the controller, but seems like a bad practice. I also thought I could override ActiveRecord::Base initializators to allow ids so my first example works, but surely I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and bit hacky solution:

```
# defined in my posts controller
def post_params
  p =  params.require(:post).merge(user: current_user)
  p[:tags] = p[:tags].map do |id, value|
    value == '1' ? Tag.find(id) : nil
  end.compact!
  p
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting tags_singular_ids to your ids. You can check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many for more of the methods that has_and_belongs_to_many provides.